# Integral related with Riemann Sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-sum

Recently I found this question:
Let $f$ be a continuous function on the interval $[-3,-\sqrt{2}]$.

Find $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \int_{-4n}^{-4n+\frac{1}{n}} f(\frac{t}{n}+1) dt$.

I am sure this has to do with the fact that $f$ is integrable and its Riemann sums but I don't know where to begin with.
Any hints?

Comment: Hint: Use a change of variable $x=\frac tn+1$; note that $f$ is bounded.

Comment: I get : $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}\int_{-3}^{-3+1/n^2}f(x) dx$, but as $f$ is continuous, that integral can be written as $f(c)*\frac{1}{n^2}$, where $c\in[-3,-3+\frac{1}{n^2}]$. As $n\to\infty$, $f(c)\to f(-3)$, the denominator goes to infinity and so the limit is $0$?

Comment: @MercyKing n is the index of the sequence.

Comment: @PedroGarcía Check your change of variable. It should be $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-3}^{-3+\frac1{n^2}}f(x)\,dx,$$ not that one with a more $\frac1{n^2}$ term.

Comment: Now since $f$ is bounded, $|f(x)|\leq M$ and thus $$\left| \int_{-3}^{-3+\frac1{n^2}}f(x)\,dx\right|\leq M\cdot\frac1{n^2}.$$ Can you finish from here?

Comment: By squeeze theorem, the limit is $0$, right?

Comment: Yes, the limit is $0$.